# Adding information/attributes to Delimited Text Layer or points on a QGIS Map

Tags: qgis, point, google-earth

I have a .kml file which has all the project locations for the projects we have done in the past. These Places on Google Earth Pro shows a point that I can click to get some basic information about any given project. See image below:

[image]

I am trying to create something similar in QGIS. So far, I have created a Delimited test layer to show the project locations. However, these are just point on the map. How do I add attributes such as Project No., Name etc., as shown in the image above. See image below to see what I have in QGIS so far:

[image]

How do I add this information to these points? I think I may be on a completely wrong track. If so, what should I do instead to achieve the desired end result on having "smart points" on a QGIS map that I can click on to get project information.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE ! IMHO, take a look at this part of QGIS documentation : https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#display-properties

Comment: Thank you! This definitely takes me in the right direction.